# can't passing parameter to another screen React Native

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-navigation

i'm using react navigation and trying to send parameter from second screen to third screen

First Screen (App.js)
`this.props.navigation.navigate('Index1',{userid1:this.state.studentsS});`

Second Screen (Index.js)

`this.props.navigation.navigate('MyDealOffer',{userid3:this.props.navigation.state.params.userid1});`

**when i check the value for (this.props.navigation.state.params.userid1) it's having the correct number**

Third Screen(MyDealOffer.js)

```
componentDidMount(){
this.setState({
  parmstudentid:this.props.navigation.state.params.userid3,
})
var x = this.props.navigation.state.params.userid3;
var url = 'http://***:82/wasily/MyDealOffer.php?
UserID=${this.props.navigation.state.params.userid3}'
fetch(url,
{method:"POST"}).then((response)=>response.json()).then((responseJson)=>{
  var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged:(r1,r2)=>r1!=r2});

  this.setState({
  isLoading:false,
  cloneStudent:ds.cloneWithRows(responseJson),
  });
  })
  }

 render() {
 if(this.state.isLoading){
  return(
    <View><Text>Wait</Text></View>
   )
  }
  return (
 <View style={styles.container}>
 <Text>User Details</Text>
 <ListView
 dataSource={this.state.cloneStudent}
 renderRow={(rowData)=>
 <Text>Username : {rowData.Price} , User ID:{rowData.Price} </Text>
 }/>
 </View>
```

`

output : "user details without any data"

========================But======================
when i change in the second screen the below line

`this.props.navigation.navigate('MyDealOffer',{userid3:this.props.navigation.state.params.userid1});`
to
`this.props.navigation.navigate('MyDealOffer',{userid3:4});`
it's showing correct data in the third screen

Comment: Can you show the method from which you're calling `this.props.navigation.navigate('MyDealOffer', {...})` inside second screen index? Not only that method but also how it's being called (like from a button click). For example say you have it inside a method `goToNextScreen()`. And you have a button with props `onPress={this.goToNextScreen}`. You either need to change that to `onPress={this.goToNextScreen.bind(this)}` or put `this.goToNextScreen = this.goToNextScreen.bind(this)` in the constructor to enable access to any value of `this`

Comment: below the index.js code 
    render() {
    return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer}
                               onPress={this.handle1Press}>
                       <Text  style={styles.buttonText}>button</Text>
                       </TouchableOpacity>

                    </View>
        )
    }
    handle1Press = ()=> {
      const x = this.props.navigation.state.params.userid1;
      this.props.navigation.navigate('MyDealOffer',{userid3:this.props.navigation.state.params.userid1});
    }

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `onPress={this.handle1Press}` inside your `TouchableOpacity` to `onPress={this.handle1Press.bind(this}`

Comment: still same issue

Comment: still same issue
it's working with 
    var url = `http://****:82/wasily/MyDealOffer.php?UserID=${this.props.navigation.state.params.userid3}`
but with     var url = `http://****:82/wasily/MyDealOffer.php?UserID=${this.props.navigation.state.params.userid3}` it doesn't work